# Dragula not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, drag-and-drop, dragula

I am using dragula with Meteor.

I have simply initialized dragula when the template is rendered with

```
Template.list.onRendered( function () {
  this.drake = dragula( [ this.find( 'ul' ) ] );
} );
```

My template consists of just a plain list

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
    {{#each this}}
      <li>{{text}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

But when trying to drag, I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null  [dragula.js:426]
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null  [classes.js:27]
```